# Arrays don't work correctly

Tags: arrays

I am trying to make a scientific calculator in java on a website called browxy.com (and it's in beta it may just be a bug), but when I tried using an array for the numbers and operations in the equations, it gave me errors saying I'm missing a ] and a ; on line 15, a ] and a ; on line 21, a ] and a ; on line 27, and a ] and a ; on line 33. Any help?

EDIT: (Also: I'm not done yet.)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ScientificCalculator {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter an equation.(No spaces)");
    Scanner raw = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = raw.nextLine();
    char[] op;
    int opNumDefineCounter = 0;
    int[] nums;
    int numDefineLocation = 0;
    for (int i; i > input.length; i = i + 1) {
        if (input.substring(i, i+1).equals("+")) {
            op[opNumDefineCounter] = "+";
            opNumDefineCounter = opNumDefineCounter + 1;
            int[opNumDefineCounter] = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(numDefineLocation, i));
            numDefineLocation = i+1;
        }
        else if (input.substring(i, i+1).equals("-")) {
            op[opNumDefineCounter] = "-";
            opNumDefineCounter = opNumDefineCounter + 1;
            int[opNumDefineCounter] = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(numDefineLocation, i));
            numDefineLocation = i+1;
        }
        else if (input.substring(i, i+1).equals("/")) {
            op[opNumDefineCounter] = "/";
            opNumDefineCounter = opNumDefineCounter + 1;
            int[opNumDefineCounter] = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(numDefineLocation, i));
            numDefineLocation = i+1;
        }
        else if (input.substring(i, i+1).equals("*")) {
            op[opNumDefineCounter] = "*";
            opNumDefineCounter = opNumDefineCounter + 1;
            int[opNumDefineCounter] = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(numDefineLocation, i));
            numDefineLocation = i+1;
        }
        else {
            //nothing happens
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: They are sintax errors. Please put here the log console of the errors that it gives to you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Java expert, but this looks wrong:

```
int[opNumDefineCounter]
```

`int` is, of course, a data type and thus a reserved word. But you use the expression above four times, on lines that correspond to your error messages. I'm pretty sure you meant to use your variable `nums`, like this:

```
nums[opNumDefineCounter]
```